# Resolving promise in nodejs server after data comes from another call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a few promises in my node server that after they all resolve the server renders to the client. I am using `Promise.all([ ...` that has all the data from the few promises I have.

I now however need some data from another call before one of my promises resolves. But it seems `Promise.all` is still resolving before I have what I need.

```
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    needDataFromThisCall(someInfo)
    .then((data) => {
        return resolve(sortData(data))
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        //error handle
    })
})
.then((resolvedData) => {
    return resolvedData;
})
```

This does not seem to work because the final `.then` the resolvedData is `undefined` and seems to get resolved before I get into my `sortData` function. Does the `return resolve(sortData...` not end up giving its return value to the final `.then`?

How should this really be done so `myPromise` can resolve after I have that data needed to send to `sortData`?

Comment: Did you verify that `data` is resolved before calling `sortData` on it?

Comment: Show all your code, the part with `Promise.all` and `sortData`.

Comment: @Rowland I have. The data is there that gets sent to sortData

Comment: What does `sortData` return? A promise? Because I'm thinking you might not need another promise constructor hence the need to share more of your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code works fine. Assuming `sortData` is synchronous function, you need to resolve `myPromise` to get the result.

```js
let someInfo = [2,3,1];

let needDataFromThisCall = info => new Promise(res => setTimeout(()=>res(info), 500) );

let sortData = data => data.sort();

const myPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    needDataFromThisCall(someInfo)
    .then((data) => {
        return resolve(sortData(data))
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        //error handle
    })
})
.then((resolvedData) => {
    return resolvedData;
})

myPromise.then(data => console.log('final data', data))
```

Comment: you don't need last line, put `console.log('final data', resolvedData);` in first `myPromise.then()`